# How to make a block-based instrumentation for C code?

Tags: parsing, code-coverage, antlr, antlr4, instrumentation

I am trying to instrument a piece of C code for code coverage. I am trying to achieve the block-based code coverage as mentioned [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phuene/2007/05/03/code-coverage-instrumentation/). And for a simple program as below:

```
int f()
{
    if (a)
    {
        printf("aaaaa");
    }
    else if (b)
    {
        printf("bbbbb");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I can make some simple instrumentation with ANTLR4 like this:

```
int f()
{/* probe here! */
    if (a)
    {/* probe here! */
        printf("aaaaa");
    }
    else if (b)
    {/* probe here! */
        printf("bbbbb");
    }
    /* ????? */
    return 1;
}
```

But according to the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phuene/2007/05/03/code-coverage-instrumentation/) above, I missed the probe at `/* ????? */`.

I guess the solution lies in the parse-tree manipulation algorithm. But I am no expert at parsing yet. Anyone could shed some light? Thanks.

I am using the [ANTLR4 C grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4).

The parse tree I obtained for above code snippet is like this:

[image]

### ADD 1

To ensure the instrumentation not jeopardize anything from the *original source code*, I have to keep *all the original tokens*, such as formatting tokens like NEWLINE and WHITESPACE. So that when I output the rewritten/instrumented source code, the format can remain. Luckily ANTLR's lexer provides multiple channels for different type of tokens. But be careful with the [ANTLR token channel specification issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1555).

### ADD 2  --  9:44 AM 3/13/2018

### Some progress so far. The ternary operator `?` is not handled yet. I am wondering if there's a complete C code sample file that I can test with.

```
int f()
{/* compound statement */
    if (a)
    {/* compound statement */
        printf("aaaaa");/* after function call */
    }
    else if (b)
    {/* compound statement */
        printf("bbbbb");/* after function call */
        if (c)
        {/* compound statement */
            if(d)
                {/* selection non-compound statement child */return 0;}
            /* statment */printf("ccccc")      ;/* after function call */      
            printf("ddddd");/* after function call */
            if(d2)
            {/* compound statement */
                a1++;
                a2++;
                a3++;
                return 1;
            }
            /* statment */switch (e)
            {
                case f:/* case */
                    f1++;
                    f2++;
                    f3++;
                    func("fffff");/* after function call */
                    f4++;
                    f5++;
                    break;
                case g:/* case */
                    printf("ggggg");/* after function call */
                    break;
                case i:/* case */
                    x()     ;/* after function call */
                    if(x)
                    {/* compound statement */
                        x1();/* after function call */
                        if(y)
                            {/* selection non-compound statement child */abc();/* after function call */}
                        /* statment */x2();/* after function call */
                    }
                case h:/* case */
                default:/* default */
                    do {/* compound statement */
                        x();/* after function call */
                        if(a)
                            {/* selection non-compound statement child */return 1;}
                        /* statment */y();/* after function call */
                        z();/* after function call */
                    }while(abc);
                    /* statment */break;
            }

        }

        /* statment */while(a)
        {/* compound statement */
            x();/* after function call */
        }
        g();/* after function call */
    }

    /* statment */xxx?yyy:zzz;


}
```

Comment: Your problem is you want to put a probe in essentially every possible control flow path.   However, the AST doesn't make control flow paths obvious; after all, it is just about explicit program syntax and control flow is implicit. You need to walk over the AST to infer such flow paths.    You will find lots of tricky cases: consider what happens if you have a "return" statement deeply nested in blocks.  If you really want your head to spin, look into the details of how switch statements *really* work; they aren't the nicely structured constructs you probably think they are.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks. My work so far is inspired by your thesis about code coverage (http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf).  It's very informative. So I will ponder over the *AST walking algorithm*. I guess for a specific instrumentation location, there should exist a corresponding detection method. So in the end, I may get a bunch of such methods. If you have some other references related to such algorithms, I'd like to know it.

Comment: No specific algorithms.  You have done the most obvious ones, which is to find control flow induced by structured syntax (e.g., if-then-else, while loops, ...).   The special cases are largely where a control flow order change statement (such as return or goto or exception-throw if your language allows that) is encountered and affects the strructured control flow of surrounding statements, e.g., return in the middle of an else clause.   Mostly this requires you look at the places you aren't instrumenting and think about how to detect those cases.